# Is it possible to keep unmanaged Windows partition when installing xcp-ng to a physical drive containing it?

Tags: xen

I have read the following at XCP-ng web site:

> XCP-ng is a specialized Linux distribution, so you need to dedicate a physical disk to it. Partitioning is done automatically.

https://docs.xcp-ng.org/installation/install-xcp-ng/#5-disk-selection

Do I understand it right that there's no way existing partitions can be kept on the only physical drive that is inside my laptop where I am going to install XCP-ng?
I would like to preserve an existing Windows 11 installation partition and restore it to the grub that will come with the fresh XCP-ng installation I'm planning.